# I can't run my flutter app in my android emulators

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, android-emulator

I have tried everything on YouTube and still I am getting the same following error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
main.dart:1
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (sigterm)
```

I tried reinstalling everything from scratch, flutter, java, android studio and all the SDKs needed, don't know if I missed any. I have followed all installation instructions from YouTube and even tried installing gradle as suggested by chatGPT too. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, one of the folder names used by the project contains characters.

**Check your folder names or create the project in a new path where folder names do not contain characters.**

Usually the characters (; /, & @ !% $ ;) cause an error

Comment: That was the problem it now works. Appreciate it.